# How can I get selected text in Ace editor?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I look into docs and also pick at the source code and I dind't find anything, all I see is selection and range objects, and methods that manipulate ranges.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's better to use `editor.getSelectedText()` instead.

Comment: It seems that not all versions support getSelectedText, for example the one from the link does not http://sweetme.at/2013/09/10/how-to-turn-your-browser-into-a-text-editor-with-syntax-highlighting/

Comment: that's a very ancient version of ace, you shouldn't use it, update to the latest version from cdnjs jsdelivr or github

Answer (score 6):

Found in Ace editor source code:

```
editor.getSession().doc.getTextRange(editor.selection.getRange());
```